# C# How to remove text between BBCode

Tags: c#, regex, bbcode

How to remove all text between BBCode Quotation (including BBCode itself):

```
[quote date=2011-07-02 14:43:53 user=test link=1]blabla[/quote]
```

I must add that between tags can be text with HTML tags for formating.
My current attempt looks like:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[quote+].+?[/\+quote]");
```

Well it's almost working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your BBCode blocks contains attributes, a simple *+* won't suffice to cover everything. + means to repeat the specified range of characters, in this case *e*.

On the top of my head, I'd try something like this:

```
 \[quote([^\[]*)\](.*?)\[\/quote\]
```

Please bear in mind that I have not tested this for C#, where the syntax might be different depending on the interpreter. Also note that I've added selection groups so that you'd be able to examine the result of each expression. As @Howard answered, [ *and* ] are reserved symbols and consequently needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 3):

You may try the following regex:

```
@"\[quote.*\].*?\[/quote\]"
```

Note that you have to escape square brackets in a regex.